# zsh bindkey does not change behavior of up and down arrow keys

Tags: linux, command-line, zsh

I want to change the key bindings of the up and down arrow keys. By default I have:

```
bindkey
...
"^[[A" up-line-or-history
"^[[B" down-line-or-history
...
```

I have added these lines to my .zshrc:

```
bindkey '^[[A' up-line-or-search
bindkey '^[[B' down-line-or-search
```

This does not change the behavior, although the bindings have changed:

```
bindkey
...
"^[[A" up-line-or-search
"^[[B" down-line-or-search
...
```

I can bind up-line-or-search to other keys, such as '^R' just fine. This problem persists in both emacs mode and vim mode. I am binding the correct keys:

```
showkey -a

Press any keys - Ctrl-D will terminate this program

^[[A  27 0033 0x1b
      91 0133 0x5b
      65 0101 0x41
^[[B  27 0033 0x1b
      91 0133 0x5b
      66 0102 0x42
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`showkey` might not actually show you the right key codes.

It looks like your shell is probably configured to tell the terminal to go into “application” mode (`smkx`), whenever the Zsh line editor starts, and into “normal” mode (`rmkx`), whenever the line editor finishes. If so, your terminal will send `^[OA` for ⬆️ when editing the command line (or in apps that tell the terminal to use application mode, such as `less`), but `^[[A` otherwise, such as when using `showkey -a` or `cat -v`.

It's often more reliable to press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>V</kbd> on the command line, followed by the key you want to check, since then you're guaranteed to be in the right mode. This works in both `emacs` and `viins` key maps.

However, even this will fail for some combinations of keys, most notably those involving backspace. To get the escape codes for even those, you'll have to create a custom keybinding in your `.zshrc`:

```sh
bindkey '^[v' .describe-key-briefly
```

Then (after you restart your shell) you can press <kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>V</kbd> to see the output for truly any combination of keys (except <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>C</kbd>, which you cannot bind anyway).

Comment: In other words, do: `bindkey '^[OA' up-line-or-search` and `bindkey '^[OB' down-line-or-search`.